# Not able to call two javascript functions

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to put some pieces of code together. I have been able to load a navegation bar in my web page, It works perfectly. I have also been able to execute a php function using AJAX, it returns some values and print them in my web page. The problem is Im not able to put together those codes, It just does not work.

This is my code for executing the php function using AJAX:

funcion_calcular.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#boton").click(function() {
        var val = $('#IBC').val();
        var porcentaje_riesgos =
            $('[name=porcentaje_riesgos]:checked').val();
        var exento_salud = $('[name=exento_salud]:checked').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'costo_empleado.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                "IBC": val,
                "porcentaje_riesgos": porcentaje_riesgos,
                "exento_salud": exento_salud
            },
            success: function(response) {
                $('#resultado').html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And I use it inside my HTML like:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="funcion_calcular.js"></script>
```

After that I have this for loading my nabber:

```html
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(document).ready(function(){                 
        $('#header').load('barra_navegacion.html');
   });
</script>
```

Navigation bar is showing properly the problem is the function (funcion_calcular) won't execute anymore. In console it says ".ajax is not a function". If I use those code separate, they work perfectly.

This is my barra_navegacion.html code:

```
<header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="mis_procesos.html">Mis Procesos</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="empresas.html">Empresas <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="mis_procesos.html">Trabajadores</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contactanos</a>
           </li>
          </ul>
          <div>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Ingresar</a>
        </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: Check in dev tools (F12) if you don't have 404 error maybe you've written the name of the file wrong, since it have typo.

Comment: You can alter the sequence of script tags, like nav loading first then loading calcular js.

Comment: are you sure it isn't because of you are using two document ready inside the same file?

Comment: @FarhanQasim it should matter. You should be able to use as many jQuery dom ready events as you want.

Comment: I got this error in console, but just when try to load nabvar,  If I do not load nabvar, everything works fine:
       TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...$.ajax...')

Comment: You'll probably want to show the navigation html code and whatever code contains 'exento_salud' and 'boton' dom elements. And when you say you can use the code blocks separately, are you saying by commenting out each script block, things work? Or do you mean in separate html pages?

Comment: If I comment the nabvar, my function executes perfectly. When I do not comment nabvar, the only thing stop working is the function which says .ajax is not a function.